# Docker image for AzureDevops self hosted agents for build .NET5 WPF Apps

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

My goal is to connect multiple docker agents in AzureDevops to build my apps.
What I need is:

- dotnet build (for .NET5 WPF applications)
- dotnet test
- publish artifacts

Is there a Docker Image with AzureDevops connection service with preinstalled .NET?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of all the Microsoft-owned images that are currently available through MCR: [Docker Hub - Microsoft images](https://hub.docker.com/publishers/microsoftowner). Looking through the list, you might be interested in image [`.NET SDK`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk), for instance. There are several .NET 5 images in there for both Linux and Windows (which you probably need because of WPF).

> This image contains the .NET SDK which is comprised of three parts:
>
> 1. .NET CLI
> 2. .NET runtime
> 3. ASP.NET Core
>    Use this image for your development process (developing, building and testing applications).

Next to that, this GitHub repo might also be helpful if you want to build your own image based on the Microsoft hosted ones: [GitHub Actions Virtual Environments](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments).

> This repository contains the source used to create the virtual environments for GitHub Actions hosted runners, as well as the VM images of Microsoft-hosted agents used for Azure Pipelines. To build a VM machine from this repo's source, see the [instructions](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/docs/create-image-and-azure-resources.md).

The instructions help you in creating your own Docker image based on the existing virtual environments used for GitHub Actions and Azure Pipelines.

**SIDENOTE:**
Please be advised that .NET 5 is *not* an LTS version. Support for .NET 5 ends **May 08, 2022**. .NET 6 has now officially been released and *is* an LTS version.

More information: [.NET and .NET Core release lifecycle - Supported versions](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core#lifecycle).